# Where is the optimal place to implement SQL retry logic when using ASP.Net TableAdapters?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, TableAdapters, and writing my code in C#.  I'm currently venturing into debugging my code after having written some data population code and I'm looking through what SQL issues I'm encountering.  At this point I want to implement some SQL retry code to handle retrying any queries if they timeout for various reason.  I can implmement them in my business logic layer but then I'd be duplicating that code in all of the BLL methods that call into my TableAdapters.  I believe I need to do this at the TableAdapter level or even somewhere higher as I have on the order of 30 or so different TableAdapters corresponding to different data.  Does anyone have any sample code on implementing code that will be run by all TableAdapters?  I have seen sample code on extending TableAdapters but I'm looking for something even more centralized for retry logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by setting the command TimeOut property = 0

```
SqlCommand.CommandTimeout
```

---

Alternatively you can put the retry logic in the DAL layer for 2-3 attempts.

Comment: How would I put the logic in the DAL layer in a central place.  When you say DAL layer I'm thinking of the set of TableAdapters I have and the set of methods that hang off of them corresponding to sprocs I've created and added to them.  How would I have retry logic in one place that all of them would use?

Comment: First, if this is only Timeout Issue, then set Timeout = 0. Otherwise, Second, In dal layer function, Put your request in try catch and the try catch in while loop. while sending request to database, in the dal Layer, In case you get error , capture it's sql error number. Now on the basis of this error number repeat three times until you get success...